# how to locate submenu elements (xpath, className or css locators)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, css-selectors, protractor

I am struggling to locate some elements in my angulars JS app using protractor (JS Webdriver).

Heres is my HTML :

```
<div id="numDispBox" ng-mouseleave="hideNumDisplayBox()" style="display: none;">
  <div class="numDispOption transition_2" ng-click="UpdateNbResultPerNode(20)">20</div>
  <div class="numDispOption transition_2" ng-click="UpdateNbResultPerNode(40)">40</div>
  <div class="numDispOption transition_2" ng-click="UpdateNbResultPerNode(60)">60</div>
  <div class="numDispOption transition_2" ng-click="UpdateNbResultPerNode(80)">80</div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able select the 2nd, 3rd and 4th inner divs.

I have used class name however it did not work :

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="UpdateNbResultPerNode(60)"]'));
```

I am not able also to find out the xpath with firebug as when I click on the inspector my submenu goes away even when I block JS mutation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use XPath to find this element.

The code would look like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@ng-click='UpdateNbResultPerNode(60)']"));
```

You can also do this by referencing the text like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='60']"));
```

Or maybe you need to first find the parent div:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='numDispBox']/div[text()='60']"));
```

I have a video on how to utilize XPath with webDriver at:
http://community.neustar.biz/community/wpm/load_testing/blog/2013/11/19/utilizing-xpath-to-interact-with-elements

Brian Kranson
Neustar, Inc. / Professional Services Engineer

Answer (score 1):

In ruby, you can do (it's the same concept for what you're trying to do with the JS Webdriver):

```
driver.find_element(:css, '#id .class:nth-child(1))
```

Comment: I do not believe that nth child selectors are zero  based.    http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: You're right.  They're not.  Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this,let me list two `selectors` which can locate the required elements.

- The one which Whitney Imura has mentioned would be a good option.

> `css = #numDispBox div:nth-child(n)`

In your case `n` can be 1,2 or 3 to locate 2nd, 3rd or 4th `div` element.

- you can also try using **+** to locate its sibling.

For example, to locate the 2nd div element the following selector would work.

> `css = #numDispBox > div + div`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use element.all:

```
element.all(by.css('#numDispBox numDispOption')).then(function(items){
  items[1].click();
  items[2].click();
  items[3].click();
});
```

or

```
element.all(by.css('#numDispBox numDispOption')).get(1)
element.all(by.css('#numDispBox numDispOption')).get(2)
element.all(by.css('#numDispBox numDispOption')).get(3)
```